# Should an enum have 2 separate value sets if they are related?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

This question is on the reuse of the Java Enums

Let's say I have an Enum

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}
```

Now, in one of the business usecase, I also need to consider Today, Tomorrow and yesterday as Days. Though they are related concepts, but clubbing them in the same enum doesn't feel right.

Should we create a new enum or can there be any justification to overload the same Days enum and add these 3 values inside it.

```
public enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY SATURDAY, SUNDAY, TODAY, TOMORROW, YESTERDAY
}
```

UPDATE1 :
The above enums are only representational just to put forth the use case.
the enum I have in code base is something business specific, but idea is that the new enum values are related in similar vague kind in the above example, but they definitely belong to different value set.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel (**again**). Use the classes in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). See [`DayOfWeek.plus(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#plus-long-).

Comment: I'd recommend using a different enum as the 2 have different meanings. Even though they both refer to days they are related to different things: week days are related to a week while Yesterday etc. is related to the current day. Also think of it that way: enum values for a set so a piece of data can only have one value (e.g. a week day). If you'd mix week days and offsets like TODAY then "today" could have 2 meanings: TODAY and MONDAY.

Comment: From that proposed enumeration, it appears to follow that TOMORROW is not one of MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, or SUNDAY.  In other words, no, I probably would not do that.

Comment: @Elliot : The above enums are only representational just to put forth the use case. 
the enum I have in code base is something business specific and not weekdays :) , but idea is that the new enum values are related in similar vague kind in the above example

Answer (score 2):

You can implement functions instead of extending the given `enum` e.g.

```
enum Days {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(yesterday(Days.SUNDAY)); // SATURDAY
        System.out.println(yesterday(Days.MONDAY)); // SUNDAY
        System.out.println(yesterday(Days.TUESDAY)); // MONDAY

        System.out.println(tomorrow(Days.SUNDAY)); // MONDAY
        System.out.println(tomorrow(Days.MONDAY)); // TUESDAY
        System.out.println(tomorrow(Days.TUESDAY)); // WEDNESDAY
    }

    static Days yesterday(Days day) {
        Days[] days = Days.values();
        int ordinal = day.ordinal();
        int index = ordinal == 0 ? days.length - 1 : ordinal - 1;
        return days[index];
    }

    static Days tomorrow(Days day) {
        Days[] days = Days.values();
        int ordinal = day.ordinal();
        int index = ordinal == days.length - 1 ? 0 : ordinal + 1;
        return days[index];
    }

    static Days today(Days day) {
        return day;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, today and tomorrow are relative positions of the current day of the week and are not values. This is the reason methods are useful: to declare that something is related to something else. So, using DayOfWeek:

```
DayOfWeek yesterday(DayOfWeek day){ return day.plus(-1);}

DayOfWeek today(DayOfWeek day){ return day;}

DayOfWeek tomorrow(DayOfWeek day){ return day.plus(1);}
```

Which is simpler to implement. But using your enum:

```
Days yesterday(Days day){ 
  return day.ordinal() == 0 ? 
    Days.values()[Days.SUNDAY.ordinal()]: 
    Days.values()[day.ordinal()-1];
}

Days today(Days day){ return day; }

Days tomorrow(Days day){
  return day.ordinal() == 6 ? 
    Days.values()[Days.MONDAY.ordinal()]: 
    Days.values()[day.ordinal()-1];
}
```

Comment: Why `day.plus(-1)` and not `day.minus(1)`?

Comment: the usecase I have is for an enum which have business specific values. I just wanted to demostrate the vague relationship between new values and older values with the help of Week days example. I have similar vague relationship for the new values that needs to be added. So was contemplating on either creating a new enum or reusing the existing one

Comment: Can you explain the nature of the relationship for your business case?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way, but if there is, it is definitely not ideal. The comments are also describe this issue perfectly. An enum is a set of defined values for a singular purpose. Whilst 'days of the week' and 'relative day' might yield the same results, it is not ideal.

So for neatness sake, I suggest that you use a different enum value for each one, if you need enums specifically and not like how @Victor (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67776586/6035548) wrote it in his answer